# Is there a better way to do square in a list rather than this?

Tags: scala

I am trying to simplify a square call.

Is this the best way?

```
(1 to 10).map(x => x*x)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declare this once somewhere:

```
def sqr(x: Int) = x * x
```

And use it like this afterwards:

```
(1 to 10).map(sqr)
```

Comment: Why is this better? Is it actually faster?

Comment: You can drop the redundant underscore: `(1 to 10).map(sqr)`.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Oups, my bad.

Comment: It is syntactically simpler. It is not faster at all - the anonymous object still has to be created, and unless the JIT inlines `sqr`, it is even slower (although you will never notice it, since the cost of everything else in the `map` on a list outweighs this difference). If you want faster, consider declaring: `val sqr = (x: Int) => x * x`. This way you can avoid creating the function object at each callsite.

Answer (score 8):

Since squaring is exponentiation to the power 2, it makes sense to consider the following two approaches:

```
scala> (1 to 10).map(math.pow(_, 2))
res6: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Double] = Vector(1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0, 25.0, 36.0, 49.0, 64.0, 81.0, 100.0)

scala> (1 to 10).map(BigInt(_).pow(2))
res7: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.math.BigInt] = Vector(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is possibly a bit overkill, but it's reasonably simple and kind of cool:

```
object SquareApp extends App {
    implicit class SquareableInt(i: Int) extends AnyVal { def squared = i*i }

    (0 until 10).map(_ squared)
}
```

The `implicit` function automatically converts any Int on which `squared` is called into a  `SquareableInt` object temporarily.

Comment: In a current version of Scala, the first two lines become just `implicit class SquareableInt(val i: Int) extends AnyVal { def squared = i*i }`.

Comment: Even cooler.  Edited my answer. I'm still just learning this implicit stuff. Thanks.